# Can't set new value to Model's property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to set new value to Model's property but it's not working. I am using dd() right after I set the new value but it keeps the old value.

```
$business->users()
    ->where('userable_id', $business->id)
    ->where('userable_type', 'App\Models\Business')
    ->first()->first_name = "New";
```

Comment: You want to change model (in-memory object) or database field?

Comment: db field. I tried $business->users()->where('userable_id', $business->id)->where('userable_type', 'App\Models\Business')->first()->save(); but again it's not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```php
$business->users()
    ->where('userable_id', $business->id)
    ->where('userable_type', 'App\Models\Business')
    ->first()->update(['first_name' => "New"]);
```

Direct object property assign like `$model->attribute = 'foo';` affects only in-memory state and doesn't make changes in the database.

So you want to go either

```php
$model->update(['attribute' => 'value']);
```

or

```php
$model->attribute = 'value';
$model->save();
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

---

Update 1:

as I've written in the comments to my answer, `first()` might return `null` sometimes if no one model was found. I'd like to advice `firstOrFail()` instead.

Note, that there is no [predefined handler](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L47) for [`ModelNotFound`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException.html) exeption (thrown by `firstOrFail()`), so you'd like to handle such error manually in `Handler` class, otherwise you'll get default 404 Laravel page.

Comment: "The update method expects an **array** of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated." `->update('first_name', "New")` should be `->update(['first_name' =>  "New"])`. The code that you have at the minute will throw an error.

Comment: So, let's dig further. Try `firstOrFail()` instead `first()`. That'll prevent from exceptions like "object A doesn't have attribute B".

Answer (score 3):

```php
$business->users()
    ->where('userable_id', $business->id)
    ->where('userable_type', 'App\Models\Business')
    ->first()->update(['first_name' => 'New']);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a method/field right after the `->first()` method is a very bad practice.

If no model is found, PHP will raise an error because you are trying to access method/property on a `null` value.

Use instead

```
$user = $business->users()
    ->where('userable_id', $business->id)
    ->where('userable_type', 'App\Models\Business')
    ->first();
$user->first_name = 'New';
$user->save();

// or, if 'first_name' is in your model $fillable array
$user->update(['first_name' => 'new' ]);
```

Comment: Aha, `;` after `first()`?)